# Return value from mongodb (not array) using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to return a single value from my model so I can compare it to the the current time in my middleware. Everything I'm finding in the mongoose docs is to [return an array](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)... how do I just get my value for key 'event_start' out of below:

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  event_name: String,
  venue_name: String,
  address: String,
  event_start: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Date & time of event start required']
    },
  event_end: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Date & time of event end required']
  },
}
```

Here's what I have so far in my function. I'd like to find by id (can update below) since I have the event_id object stored in req.params:

```
module.exports.expiredEvent = (req, res, next) => { 
   const { id } = req.params;
   const event = Event.find({ "_id": id })
```

How do I return the value for event_start from my db instead of an object?

Comment: did you try `Event.find({},{_id:0,event_start:1});`, this will still return an object but only contains `event_start`

Comment: hey @YahiaBadr - I modified yours a bit because it was giving me *all* event_start values and I only want for a specific event `const event = Event.find({ "_id" : id },{_id:0,event_start:1}).then(data => console.log(data));` 
 However, this returns the [{ key: value }]. Any idea how I get just the value?

Comment: is it posible to await for result and return required info, as follow...........


module.exports.expiredEvent = async (req, res, next) => { 
   const { id } = req.params;
   const event = await Event.find({ "_id": id }, {_id:0,event_start:1});
  return event[0].event_start;
}

Comment: Wow @ShashikamalRC great call, updated code `const eventTimes = await Event.find({ "_id" : id },{_id:0, event_start:1});
    console.log(eventTimes);` returns the array `[ { event_start: 2022-01-13T17:26:00.000Z } ]`. So same issue as above but code is much cleaner.. how could I get just the value?

Comment: While returning do eventTimes[0].event_start.     since we are finding with id, for sure we will be having single object. So we can access it with 0 and return a required field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports.expiredEvent = async (req, res, next) => { 
   const { id } = req.params;
   const event = await Event.find({ "_id": id }, {_id: 0, event_start: 1});
   console.log(event); // [{event_start: 2022-01-13T17:26:00.000Z}]
   return event[0].event_start; // this will return 2022-01-13T17:26:00.000Z
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I modified the last line to save the return in a variable  `const startTime = event[0].event_start;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using mongoose, you should try `findById`:

```
Event.findById(id, "event_start").exec();
```

Refer the [document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) for more details.